# How to create a multiprocessing Queue with set_start_method?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to create `multiprocessing.Queue` that is referenced in a `Pool` created within `main()`. However, using this code:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(_):
    print(b)

def main():
    print("main")
    print(b)

    print("running f")
    f(0)

    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.map(f, list(range(2)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    b=mp.Queue()

    main()
```

I get `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`. This code runs fine without the `mp.set_start_method('spawn')` call. How can I define a global `Queue` object that will be visible to `f()` and still use the `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`?

Comment: you are trying to treat `b` as a global, but globals are not shared with child processes. you must explicitly pass the queue as an argument at the creation of the child process (in this case in `initargs` which go with the initialization function in the `Pool` constructor. For various reasons, they cannot be sent later after the creation of the child process is complete.

Comment: When you use "fork" globals are (kind of) shared, so it works more in-line with what you would expect from a single process structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` to initialize global variable `b` for each pool process:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

# Initialize each pool process:
def init_pool(q):
    global b

    b = q

def f(_):
    print(b, b.get())

def main():
    print("main")
    print(b)

    print("running f")
    f(0)

    with mp.Pool(2, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(b,)) as pool:
        pool.map(f, list(range(2)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    b=mp.Queue()
    b.put(1)
    b.put(2)
    b.put(3)

    main()
```

Prints:

```None
main
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x00000192041E38E0>
running f
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x00000192041E38E0> 1
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x000001843E12A190> 2
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x000001843E12A190> 3
```